# Showing equivalence between norm and norm defined by a Schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach Space with norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Schauder basis of $X$, let $x=\sum c_n x_n$, define a new norm $$\{\{x\}\}=\sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \left\|\sum_{n=1}^N c_n x_n\right\|$$
I need to show that those two norms on $X$ are equivalent.
I already showed that $\|\cdot\|$ is less then or equal to $\{\{\cdot \}\}$ and I need the other ineqality $\{\{ \cdot\}\} \leq C \|\cdot\|$ for some $C> 0$. Tried some basic evaluations but couldn't make it work

Thanks

Comment: Try to show that $X$ is also complete with respect to the other norm.

Comment: This follows from the easy inequality, no?
A caushy sequence in the {{ }} norm is also caushy in || || and therefore converges. How do I porceed?
I can take maybe a sequence y_n with || || norm 1/n and {{ }} norm 1(if I assume by contradiction they are not equivalent), and get a contradiction? Im not so sure how to do it.. It converging to 0 in the || || norm, how can I claim it is caushy in the {{ }} norm?

Comment: It's not so easy. It converges with respect to $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, but that does not directly imply that it converges with respect to $\{\{\cdot\}\}$.

Comment: So how do I use the completness of $X$ with respect to the second norm?

Comment: I really don't understand what prevents c_1 to be 1/2(and therefore {{ }} is at least 1/2) for a point with norm as small as I wish, this doesn't sound true when I think about it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your norm is actually given by:$\newcommand{\vertiii}[1]{{\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert\kern-0.25ex\left\vert #1 
    \right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert\kern-0.25ex\right\vert}}$

$$\vertiii x  = \sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \left\|\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n(x)x_n\right\|$$

where $\alpha_n(x)$ is the unique scalar coefficient with $x_n$ in the above representation of $x \in X$.

As you mentioned, we have:

$$\|x\| = \left\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n(x)x_n \right\| = \left\|\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(x)x_n \right\|= \lim_{N\to\infty}\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(x)x_n \right\| \le \sup_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \left\|\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n(x)x_n\right\| = \vertiii x $$

For the converse inequality, we will show that $X$ equipped with $\vertiii{\cdot}$ is a Banach space.

Let $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence with respect to $\vertiii{\cdot}$. We have to show it converges with respect to $\vertiii{\cdot}$.

First notice that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence $\big(\alpha_n(f_j)\big)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of scalars. Indeed, for any $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

\begin{align}
\left|\alpha_n(f_i) - \alpha_n(f_j)\right|\|x_n\| &= \|\alpha_n(f_i - f_j)x_n\|\\
&= \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_n(f_i - f_j)x_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \alpha_n(f_i - f_j)x_n\right\|\\
&\le \left\|\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_n(f_i - f_j)x_n\right\| + \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \alpha_n(f_i - f_j)x_n\right\|\\
&\le 2\vertiii{f_i - f_j} \xrightarrow{i, j \to \infty} 0
\end{align}

$\big(\alpha_n(f_j)\big)_{j=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence of scalars so it converges: $\alpha_n(f_j) \xrightarrow{j\to\infty} \beta_n$. The idea now is to show that

$$f_j = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n(f_j)x_n \xrightarrow{j\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\beta_nx_n$$

with respect to $\vertiii{\cdot}$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is Cauchy, there exists $j_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $i, j \ge j_0$ holds:

$$\vertiii{f_i - f_j} < \frac\varepsilon4$$

For $i, j \ge j_0$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(f_i)x_n - \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(f_j)x_n\right\| = \left\|\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(f_i - f_j)x_n\right\| \le  \vertiii{f_i - f_j} < \frac\varepsilon4$$

Letting $j \to \infty$ here gives:

$$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(f_i)x_n - \sum_{n=1}^N \beta_nx_n\right\|   \le \frac\varepsilon4$$

Furthermore, for any $M, N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $M > N$ we have:

$$\left\|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \alpha_n(f_i)x_n - \sum_{n=M+1}^N \beta_nx_n\right\| \le \left\|\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n(f_i)x_n - \sum_{n=1}^N \beta_nx_n\right\| + \left\|\sum_{n=1}^M \alpha_n(f_i)x_n - \sum_{n=1}^M \beta_nx_n\right\| \le \frac\varepsilon4 + \frac\varepsilon4  =\frac\varepsilon2$$

Now, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n(f_{j_0})x_n$ converges, there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $M, N \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$N > M \ge N_0 \implies \left\|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \alpha_n(f_{j_0})x_n\right\| \le \frac\varepsilon4$$

So for all $M, N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $N > M \ge N_0$ we have:

$$\left\|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \beta_nx_n\right\|\le  \left\|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \alpha_n(f_{j_0})x_n\right\| + \left\|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \alpha_n(f_{j_0})x_n -
 \sum_{n=M+1}^N \beta_nx_n\right\| \le \frac\varepsilon4 + \frac\varepsilon2 = \frac{3\varepsilon}4 < \varepsilon$$

So, $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \beta_nx_n\right)_{N=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X, \|\cdot\|)$. We conclude that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n x_n$ converges. Set $f = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n x_n$.

Because $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder basis, the representation $f = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \beta_n x_n$ is unique so we in fact have $\beta_n = \alpha_n(f)$.

Finally, for $i \ge j_0$ we have:

$$\vertiii{f_i - f} = \sup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n(f_i - f)x_n\right\| = \sup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N\alpha_n(f_i)x_n - \sum_{n=1}^N\beta_nx_n\right\| \le \frac\varepsilon4 < \varepsilon$$

We conclude $f_j \xrightarrow{\vertiii{\cdot}} f$ so $(X, \vertiii{\cdot})$ is complete.

---

Recall the [Bounded Inverse Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem):

> Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $A : X \to Y$ a bounded invertible linear map. Then $A^{-1} : Y \to X$ is also bounded.

Consider the identity map $I : (X, \vertiii{\cdot}) \to (X, \|\cdot\|)$. Since $\|\cdot\| \le \vertiii{\cdot}$, we have that $I$ is bounded. Both $(X, \vertiii{\cdot})$ and $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ are Banach spaces so the identity in the reverse direction $I : (X, \|\cdot\|) \to (X, \vertiii{\cdot})$ is also bounded.

Therefore, there exists $C > 0$ such that

$$\vertiii x = \vertiii{Ix} \le C\|x\|$$

We conclude that $\|\cdot\|$ and $\vertiii{\cdot}$ are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you!
It is indeed a bit messy, but pretty much straight forward.